# How to view the actual bytes in a Data variable in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode10.1

I have a variable of type Data in Swift code, using Xcode 10.1, called data. I can see it in the debugger, but I don't know where the actual values are stored. It should contain a letter (one byte) and three Uint8 values, all 0-255, so it should be 4 bytes. The first _length is shown to be 6, so i don't know what else could be added in (one reason I want to see what is actually in there) (below). But I do not understand where the binary value is. The _rawValue does not seem to be it because it contains 4.5 bytes. Perhaps it is a pointer, as it says "RawPointer"?

Where are the actual bytes stored?
[image]

Edit:
By setting a new variable equal to data[i], i did figure out the number of bytes is correct (I found the code was putting things in i didn't know). My string is, for example "!C 0 21 255 17", so 6 bytes.

However, I would still love to find an answer to my question: Is there way during debug to view the elements without creating new variables to inspect?

Comment: Note that data conforms to random access collection. You can check each byte (UInt8) value using subscript like `data[0]`. You can also just print is as an Array. `print(Array(data))`

Comment: You need only 3 bytes to store 3 x UInt8 values. You need only one byte for each UInt8. 1 byte = 8 bits

Comment: When displaying data as hexa you need two hexa values for each byte (0...9)+(a...f) = 16. 16x16 = 256 (0...255)

Comment: Yes, i am tired! @LeoDabus you're of course right about the number of bytes. I could create a new variable byte0 = data[0] and view that in the debugger, but isn't there a way to see data[0] in the debugger directly?

Comment: I've corrected the question.

Comment: Can you add your bytes values and the expected output (letter and values)

Comment: @LeoDabus i added the info you requested, so at the end of the day I have solved my coding problem, but i would still like to know how to inspect the variable data while debugging. Maybe not possible, perhaps just contains pointers?

Answer (score 3):

Create an extension of Data as follows:

```
extension Data {
    public var bytes: [UInt8]
    {
        return [UInt8](self)
    }
}
```

You can view the bytes of data during debugging as:

```
po data.bytes
```

Comment: This is a simple and easy solution. Definitely saved me some time!

Answer (score 2):

Just type `po data as NSData` in the debug console. You will see the hex bytes like `<066465666768>`